# Python: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def get_data(fp):
    data = []
    for line in fp:
        line_list_ints = [int(number) for number in line.split()]
        data.append(line_list_ints)
    return data

def calculate_grades(data):
    for line in data:
        total_points = sum(line[1:6])
        grade = get_grade(total_points)
        data.insert(0,total_points)
        data.insert(1,grade)
    return data
```

I am getting the TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable for line 10. I do not understand why as I convert the numbers into ints before I append them into the data list. Can anyone help? Am I being clear enough?

Comment: Why are you slicing from 1 to 6 on line?

Comment: I need to add just the numbers in spots [1:6] from each line

Comment: how do I do a full traceback?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're modifying the `data` list while you're iterating over it, using `data.insert` in `calculate_grades`. This leads to the second iteration of the loop to see the `grade` value from the previous iteration as `line`, rather than the list of integers it is expecting.

I don't entirely understand what you're trying to do, so I can't suggest a solution directly. Perhaps you should make a separate list for the output, or modify `line` in place, rather than inserting a new item into `data`.

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem is because there are floats in data (eventually)

```
for line in data:
    total_points = sum(line[1:6])
    grade = get_grade(total_points)
    data.insert(0,total_points)
    data.insert(1,grade)
```

Because you insert it into your list, as 'grade'

The general problem is that you are modifying your list ('data') while you iterate over it, which is a bad idea - your logic will be hard to read at best, and easily loop forever.

Comment: See also - what Blckknght said

Answer (score 0):

Uh, the issue is the part `line[1:6]` in line 10. The variable `line` is a float, so you can't take a sublist.

Comment: I'm not sure why `line` is a float. It depends on the value of the parameter `data` that you pass to calculate_grade. It's probably a list of floats, and since `line` is an element of `data`, it is also a float.

Comment: Can you post the full code, so I can see the code that calls `calculate_grades`?

Comment: fp = open("data.short.txt")
    data = get_data(fp)
    grades = calculate_grades(data)