# Error when trying to get a list of values from darksky API

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

What I'm trying to accomplish: I'm trying to get a list of Max Temperatures, Min Temperatures and the Time for the next 7 days from the darksky API. I keep getting this (TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable) when I attempt to print the variable. The end result is to import this data into a Dataframe using pandas, the code isn't finished obviously.

Again the answer may be obvious (newb here). Thank's for the help all!

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests
import json 

key = '(my dark sky api key)'
url = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/%s/43.0481221,-76.147424' % (key)
response = requests.get(url)
weather_data = response.json()
time = weather_data['currently']['apparentTemperature']['daily']['data'][0:8]['time']
temperature_min = weather_data['currently']['apparentTemperature']['daily']['data'][0:8]['apparentTemperatureMin']
temperature_max = weather_data['currently']['apparentTemperature']['daily']['data'][0:8]['apparentTemperatureMax']

print(temperature_min)

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991591/typeerror-float-object-is-not-subscriptable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223059/python-typeerror-float-object-is-not-subscriptable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243174/how-to-fix-typeerror-float-object-is-not-subscriptable-and-an-append-that-is are not of any help?

Comment: Instead of chaining `__getitem__` try to get each subsequent value separately and print them out for debugging purposes. One of those is a float which you try  to use like a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently the problem is with data structure and indexing you are trying to use for retrieving the required data.

`weather_data['currently']` would give you the dictionary object:

```
{'apparentTemperature': 57.44,
 'cloudCover': 0.29,
 'dewPoint': 33.07,
 'humidity': 0.4,
 'icon': 'partly-cloudy-day',
 'nearestStormBearing': 242,
 'nearestStormDistance': 436,
 'ozone': 358.37,
 'precipIntensity': 0,
 'precipProbability': 0,
 'pressure': 1028.68,
 'summary': 'Partly Cloudy',
 'temperature': 57.44,
 'time': 1492546503,
 'visibility': 10,
 'windBearing': 4,
 'windSpeed': 2.16}
```

`weather_data['currently']['apparentTemperature']` gives the `float` number `57.44`. When you further try to subscript the error is raised because the float number is not subscriptable. I would suggest  to investigate more the `weather_data` data structure and choose the correct indexing which will give the data you need.

Try this:

```
time = [weather_data['daily']['data'][k]['time'] for k in range(0,8)]
temperature_min = [weather_data['daily']['data'][k]['apparentTemperatureMin'] for k in range(0,8)]
temperature_max = [weather_data['daily']['data'][k]['apparentTemperatureMax'] for k in range(0,8)]
```

Here the list comprehension is used for retrieving the data for 8 days. If you   would like to receive some specific days use `list` of specific days (e.g. [2,5,6] ) instead of `range(0,8)`

Comment: Was actually considering iterating as my next step, that was a big help thanks!